# With Parse.com: How do i execute something like mongo's $pull?

Tags: parse-platform

Currently I have an array object, but when i want to update this array I am worried about the array getting out of sync.  Any ideas how to solve this?  I do it with $pull in mongo but don't want race conditions with Parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could this within javascript,

```
https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Op.Remove.html
```

Or this within android:

ParseObject.addUnique & ParseObject.removeAll